# Need an explanation using kivy-buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am using Python 3.5 on Windows os, and using kivy-buildozer Vm-box to build an .apk app with Python 2.7 which it uses by default.
So, is there is a problem to use a code in Python 3.5 to be built in buildozer py 2.7?

And if it is possible, how can I change the default Python version to use 3.5 instead 2.7? Or totally I need an explanation about the whole process with these variables:

1. I am working in Windows station.
2. I need to move programming to Linux os (kivy-buildozer vm).
3. I am working in Python v-3.5, and I hate v-2.x.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there is a problem to use a code in Python 3.5 to be built in buildozer py 2.7?

No, not a problem.

> And if it is possible, how can I change the default Python version to use 3.5 instead 2.7?

This is documented [here](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#python3) - you need to use the CrystaX NDK and python3crystax requirement. You can do this with buildozer, but you need to manually download the CrystaX NDK and tell buildozer to use it.